# what does "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()" mean in random in python?

Tags: python

I created a random password generator, but, when i enter the data, it keeps showing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    password += random.choice(all[num])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 288, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

```
#Password Generator Project
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
nr_symbols = int(input("How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input("How many numbers would you like?\n"))

password = ""
all = [letters, numbers, symbols, nr_letters, nr_numbers, nr_symbols]
lenght = nr_letters + nr_numbers + nr_symbols
for x in range (0, lenght):

  num = int(random.randint(0, len(all)/2))
  password += random.choice(all[num])
  all[int(num + len(all)/2)] -= 1
  if nr_letters == 0:
    ended = all.index(nr_letters)
    all.remove(ended, int(ended - len(all)/2))
  if nr_numbers == 0:
    ended = all.index(nr_numbers)
    all.remove(ended, int(ended - len(all)/2))
  if nr_symbols == 0:
    ended = all.index(nr_symbols)
    all.remove(ended, int(ended - len(all)/2))
print(password)
```

Comment: Please provide the code in post in text format, also create [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: also the error clearly points out that `seq` is an integer and has no length, did You mean to just use `self._randbelow(seq)`

Comment: @Matiiss `seq` is defined in the `random` module, not in the `main.py` script.

Comment: Side note: [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) is a built-in function and you should avoid naming variables with that name.

Comment: Can you try changing this line `int(random.randint(0, len(all)/2))` to `int(random.randint(0, (len(all)/2) - 1))`

Comment: `random.randint`: _Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1)._  And the last 3 items of `all` are not lists.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `all` to be this:

```
all = [letters, numbers, symbols, nr_letters, nr_numbers, nr_symbols]
```

`letters`, `numbers` and `symbols` are lists, but `nr_letters`, `nr_numbers` and `nr_symbols` are integers. That means that some of the items in `all` are lists, and some are integers.

Later, in your for-loop, you use `random.randint` to generate a random index to use with `all`:

```
num = random.randint(0, len(all)/2)
```

However, `random.randint` includes both endpoints, so the possible indices are zero through three (inclusive) - that's four indices. You then use that index to select one of the items in `all` when you do `random.choice(all[num])`. When `num` is `3`, you effectively do `random.choice(nr_letters)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `chr(randint(33, 126))` to generate letters, numbers and symbols